# JEditorPane freezes even updation by EDT

Tags: java, swing

this is a java chat application.

```
Structure of program :
 1. Main thread to connect server(and listen to keyboard input)
 2. I have used EDT to initialize GUI and for action listener
 3. I have started another thread from main thread to grab server messages
```

I have a `JEditorPane` which I updates from main thread as well as from second thread. I have used EDT for the updation, still it gets freezed. I am not able to figure out where I am doing wrong or I need to refactor my code

```
public class Client extends JFrame implements Runnable,KeyListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    static Socket clientSocket=null;
    static BufferedReader is=null, in=null;
    static PrintStream os=null;
    static boolean closed=false;
    static boolean go=false;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JComboBox comboT1;
    private JComboBox comboT2;
    private JComboBox comboT3;
    static JEditorPane textArea = new JEditorPane();
    static JTextField write;
    private JButton send;


    public Client()
    {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("myStats - Client");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 350);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));



        //textArea = new JTextArea("");
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        //scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPane.SCROLLBARS_ALWAYS);

        contentPane.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        write = new JTextField();
        write.addKeyListener(this);
        send = new JButton("Send");
        //JLabel writeSomething = new JLabel("Want to send something --");

        Box Vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();     
        Box Hbox = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        Hbox.add(write);
        Hbox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(5,0)));
        Hbox.add(send);


        Vbox.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,7)));
        Vbox.add(Hbox);
        contentPane.add(Vbox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //Add my statistics
                go = true;
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",8189);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
        }
        catch(Exception e)//listening 
        {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Client frame = new Client();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


        {
            if(clientSocket!=null && os!=null && in!=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    new Thread(new Client()).start();
                    while(!closed)                         //For Keyboard Input -- Message Box
                    {   
                        while(!go);
                        os.println(write.getText());
                        write.setText("");
                        go = false;
                    }
                    os.close();
                    in.close();
                    clientSocket.close();               
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                    DoEverything("Error : "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }           
        }   
    }   

    public void run()
    {
        String response;
        try
        {
            while((response=in.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println(response);
                DoEverything(response);
                if(response.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Bye"))
                    break;
            }
            closed = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
            DoEverything("Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
        {   
            if(write.getText().length()>0)
                send.doClick();
        }
    }
    public static void DoEverything(final String mynew) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          textArea.setText(textArea.getText() +""+ mynew+"\n");       
        }
      });
    }

}
```

here is my server code

```
    public class Server
    {
        static Socket clientSocket=null;
        static ServerSocket serverSocket=null;
        static ClientThread threadCollection[] = new ClientThread[20];

        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            int i;
            try


    {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8189);  //Blocking Call -- Wait for Client
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); //get the client details (socket) to interact with them
                for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                {
                    if(threadCollection[i]==null)
                    {
                        threadCollection[i] = new ClientThread(clientSocket, threadCollection);
                        threadCollection[i].start(); //give client server thread(representative)
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}

class ClientThread extends Thread
{
    PrintStream os=null; //send the message to client
    BufferedReader is=null; //receive message from client
    Socket clientSocket=null;//client address
    ClientThread threadCollection[];//all the clients server got ~20

    public ClientThread(Socket cs, ClientThread []t)
    {
        this.clientSocket = cs;
        this.threadCollection = t;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String line = new String();
        int i;
        try
        {
            is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);


            os.println("<Server> : Hello "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());  //server sending message to client

            //name = is.readLine();  //server reading the message from client
            //os.println("Welcome '"+name+"' to chat room!");

            for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                if(threadCollection[i]!=null && threadCollection[i]!=this)
                    threadCollection[i].os.println("A new user '"+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"' joinied to accomplish today's task");

            while(true)
            {
                line = is.readLine();
                System.out.println("<"+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"> : "+line);
                if(line.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Bye"))
                    break;
                for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                    if(threadCollection[i]!=null)
                        threadCollection[i].os.println("<"+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+">: "+line);
            }

            for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                if(threadCollection[i]!=null && threadCollection[i]!=this)
                    threadCollection[i].os.println("User '"+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName()+"' has given up!!!");
            os.println("Bye "+clientSocket.getInetAddress().getHostName());

            for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                if(threadCollection[i]==this)
                    threadCollection[i]=null;

            is.close();
            os.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error : "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question is a bit unclear. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help Center, and feel free to edit your question to improve it! You may want to include information such as what you have tried or what your current thoughts are.

Comment: Its' not freezing for me. Please can you share server side code as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `go` and `closed` volatile:

```
static volatile boolean closed=false;
static volatile boolean go=false;
```

This lets the actual variables be read every time you access them. Without `volatile` one thread may not actually access the original variable, but use another value (which was valid earlier in time).

The loop `while (!go);` is a big no-no (with exclamation marks). Apart from that, without `volatile` it may end up using an outdated value for `go` without ever checking what the actual value of the go variable is in the meantime. (Simply speaking, each thread has its own copies of the variables and you need `synchronized` blocks to make a thread look for the real thing.) Or you make the variable volatile which kind of makes the variable "uncached".

With that while loop you want to wait. You may give the CPU some free time to do something else and not just occupy all of the current core:

```
while (!go) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(1);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
   }
}
```

Then after that "while (!go)" you call `write.setText("");`, but this is not in the EDT. (Well it might be in the EDT, if `main` was called from within the EDT, but that is usually not the case.) You need to wrap that for the EDT.

This might be enough to remove the freeze. 
Multithreading is hard. You should learn about wait/notify (still hard) and especially take a look at the classes in java.util.concurrent (a little less hard).

Comment: made the changes write.setText(""); in EDT , free CPU to do spmething else but still my JEditorPane freezes, can you look at my server code as sometime my JEditorPane freezes just as soon as I launch it